# Replacing numbers based in their order in a pandas column with a specific range

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, replace, integer

Stackoverflow:

I have to rearange a pandas column of int numbers by their order, (the count of unique values of the original column is 50, so this has to be done in a range from 1 to 50). This column has duplicates and they have to be remained.

For instance, if I have:

```
geodf['Areas']
0     38
1     44
2     68
3     63
4     63
5     63
6     63
7     44
8     44
9      7
10    63
11    63
12    63
13    39
14    44
```

How can I transform that into this, for all the column? (it has a size>200)

```
geodf['Areas']
0     2
1     4
2     6
3     5
4     5
5     5
6     5
7     4
8     4
9     1
10    5
11    5
12    5
13    3
14    4
```

As it can be seen, the replacing of the values depends on the order of the previous number compared to the others. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Does the answer solve your problem ?   Feel free to let me know if any further clarification required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.rank()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rank.html) with method 'dense', as follows:

```
geodf['Areas'].rank(method='dense').astype(int)
```

**Result:**

```
0     2
1     4
2     6
3     5
4     5
5     5
6     5
7     4
8     4
9     1
10    5
11    5
12    5
13    3
14    4
Name: Areas, dtype: int32
```

If you want to apply the logics to all columns in `geodf`, you can try something like:

```
for col in geodf:    # or replace 'geodf' in this line by a list of the selected columns
    geodf[col] = geodf[col].rank(method='dense').astype(int)
```